# Is the Abel-Jacobi map flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme corresponding to a smooth projective curve over $k=\bar{k}$.

Let $Div_X$ denote the set of effective Cartier divisors of $X$ and $Pic_X$ the set of line bundles over $X$. We can give scheme structures to these sets, as it is covered for example in [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504020). We can then look at the Abel-Jacobi as a morphism of schemes
$$ A:Div_X \to Pic_X\;, \qquad D\mapsto\mathcal{O}_X(D) $$
My question is: **is the Abel-JAcobi map a flat morphism?**

I guess the smoothness of $X$ is necessary to hope for a $A$ to be flat... is my intuition correct?

By the way, do you think it is possible to answer this question (loosely) by a geometrical argument?

Comment: My answer was silly, sorry. I thought you were referring to the classical AJ map, which is not flat! (Except the case P1 to point) since by the Torelli theorem it is a closed immersion. Closed immersions are most certainly not flat, contra my nonsense answer. I think you have a disjoint union of a bunch of these classical AJ maps, so also not flat.